# UFW enable X seconds a after reloading ubuntu server

Tags: 16.10, ufw

I know each time when we reload a server we have to enable the firewall. I think this is good. However I'd like to automatically enable UFW after 600 seconds sever restarted. 
In this case if we did some mistake to rules we have enough time to fix it before ufw enabled. 
If we forget to restart the firewall it will enable in 10 minutes, or restart after electrical failure.
Please Help, whats the best way to do this with minimum server load?

I'm on LEMP stack with Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: You could disable the automatic start of ufw at boot by `sudo systemctl disable ufw` and in `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0` insert the line `sleep 600; systemctl start ufw`

Comment: is there another way? rc.local not available on 16.10. can we do this without enabling rc.local?

Comment: As I am not using 16.10 (just 16.04, because of professional use) I cannot help any further. Sorry.